# Can a combination of actions make it impossible to update an iOS app in the App Store?

Tags: ios

If I have an app signed with a certain certificate and uploaded and approved on the App Store and after some time that certificate expires I can't update it until I generate another certificate, then I can update it again.

So there is no chance that I mismanage the certificates in a way that makes it impossible to update as long as I have access to the developer admin. Right?

What if the user is different, or if the one that uploaded the app no longer exists?

Answer (score 0):

Without valid certificate you can not submit `app` or `update` to `appstore`. If user is different then you have to give your certificate to that developer. Once you put your app on app store and your certificate will expire, it will not affect your app running on app store. but if you want to submit new update then you need valid certificate!